# How do I quickly list all Google Cloud projects in an organization?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I would like to quickly list all Google Cloud projects in an organization, without AppScript folders.

`gcloud projects list` can be very slow. [This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/listing-all-resources#exclude_apps_script_projects_example) is about speeding it up, but does not show how to retrieve the Appscript folder which is used for filtering. Can that be done from the command line?

Also, `gcloud projects list` does not have a way to filter by organization. It seems that that is impossible as projects are not linked to their organization except through a tree of folders.

[The documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/listing-all-resources#list_all_resources_example) shows a way of walking the  tree, apparently with [Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/list), which might do the job, but only pseudocode is shown. How can this be done with gcloud -- or else with Python or another language?

And if there is no way to accelerate this: How do I page through results using `gcloud projects list`? The documentation shows that  `page-size` can be set, but does not show how to step through page by page (presumably by sending a page number with each command).

See also below for a reference to code I wrote that is the imperfect but best solution I could find.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59852112/7215091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Unfortunately there isn’t a native Apps Script resource available to work with Cloud Resource Manager API.
- Although, it is possible to make a HTTP call directly to the Resource Manager API [projects.list()](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) endpoint with the help of [UrlFetchApp service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).
- Alternatively, using Python as mentioned, the recommended [Google APIs client library for python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) supports calls to Resource Manager API. You can find the specific projects.list() method documentation [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/cloudresourcemanager_v1.projects.html#list).
- On additional note, if you happen to use a Cloud project to generate credentials and authenticate the API call, you may want to enable Cloud Resource Manager API on your project by following [this URL](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com).
- I’d also recommend submitting a new Feature Request using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).

Comment: Thank you. Actually I'm using clojure so java would be better. Is there a java api to list all projects in an org?

Comment: Yes, within Google's github repositories, there is a Google API client library for Java as well. You may find it [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client). [Cloud Resource Manager API](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client-services/tree/main/clients/google-api-services-cloudresourcemanager/v1) is listed within the services supported by the Java client.

Comment: I wrote some code using this. See other answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that lists projects in an organization as quickly as possible. It is in Clojure, but it uses Java APIs and you can translate it easily.

Key steps

- Query all accessible projects using [CloudResourceManager](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-resourcemanager/latest/com.google.cloud.resourcemanager.v3) `projects()`, using `setQuery` to accelerate the query by filtering out, for example, the hundreds of `sys-` projects often generated by AppScript. The query uses paging.
- From the results

  - Accept those that are the child of the desired org
  - Reject those that are the child of another org.
  - For those that are the child of a folder, do this  (concurrently, for speed): Use `gcloud projects get-ancestors $PROJECT_ID` to find the projects in your organization. (I don't see a way to do that in Java, and so I call the CLI.)