# How to retrieve a spreadsheet apps script id using google api

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm looking for a way programmatically using NodeJS and google api to associate an existing apps script file(id) with a newly created spreadsheet/s or else to retrieve the associated script id from a newly created spreadsheet so I can inject a custom script code

so far I tried with google sheet api to retrieve the associated scrip id without any success, and I didn't find any documentation on how to associate a spreadsheet with an existing script id.

Comment: Try with [tag:google-apps-script-api]

Comment: I asked a similar question a long time ago.  AFAIK there is no way.  Actually I did find an answer to my question but it's not simple and it probably does not work any more because it depends upon the structure of the google website which has probably changed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59852112/7215091

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: I appreciate your quick and detailed answer, but I managed to find a simple workaround that suits my specific case, I simply using a spreadsheet template with a script project already associated with it and then duplicating the spreadsheet file using the google drive api, and passing whatever data i need to the new spreadsheet.
in my case this workaround is acceptable and working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your following question,

> I'm looking for a way programmatically using NodeJS and google api to associate an existing apps script file(id) with a newly created spreadsheet/s or else to retrieve the associated script id from a newly created spreadsheet so I can inject a custom script code

if my understanding is correct, how about the following answer?

#### Prerequisite:

First, the prerequisite is as follows.

- You have a Google Apps Script project.
- You know the script ID (file ID) of Google Apps Script.
- You create a new Google Spreadsheet and want to add the above existing Google Apps Script to the created Spreadsheet as the container-bound script.

#### Sample flow:

In the current stage, the existing Google Apps Script project cannot be directly linked as the container-bound script while keeping the script ID (file ID) of Google Apps Script. However, I thought that your goal could be achieved by creating a new Google Apps Script project to the existing Google Spreadsheet. In order to achieve this, how about the following flow?

1. Confirm the script ID (file ID) of your current Google Apps Script.

   - This script is put into the new Google Spreadsheet as the container-bound script.
2. Create a new Google Spreadsheet. And, please confirm the Spreadsheet ID of the created Spreadsheet.

   - I think that in this case, [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) or [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create) can be used.
3. Retrieve an object from your current Google Apps Script using the script ID with "[Method: projects.getContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent)".
4. Create a new container-bound script to the new Google Spreadsheet using the Spreadsheet ID with "[Method: projects.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create)". And, retrieve the script ID of the created container-bound script from the response value of the API.
5. Put the script retrieved from your current Google Apps Script into the created container-bound script using the script ID of the created container-bound script with "[Method: projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent)".

By this flow, the new Google Spreadsheet including a container-bound script of your current Google Apps Script is created. I guessed that this might be your expected result.

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that you have already been able to get and put values using Google Apps Script API.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.create](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create)
- [Method: files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create)
- [Method: projects.getContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent)
- [Method: projects.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create)
- [Method: projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent)